# Working with "AlternationCount" property of DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have problem with "AlternationCount" property of DataGrid.
I set two colors for rows' background and now when I select one of the rows and move the scrollBar, every other row will be selected too!
I've set AlternationCount="2" and SelectionMode="Single".

Could anybody solve this problem?

C# Code:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data1 = new Test { Test1 = "TestCell1", Test2 = "TestCell2", Test3 = "TestCell3" };
        var data2 = new Test { Test1 = "TestCell1", Test2 = "TestCell2", Test3 = "TestCell3" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(data1);
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(data2);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public string Test2 { get; set; }
        public string Test3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single"
            Name="dataGrid1" 
            RowBackground="Beige"
            AlternatingRowBackground="linen"
            DataContext="{Binding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="239.334" 
            Margin="39.333,37.333,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Test1}" Header="Header1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Test2}" Header="Header2" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Test3}" Header="Header3" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Test { Test1 = "TestCell1", Test2 = "TestCell2", Test3 = "TestCell3" });
            dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Test { Test1 = "TestCell1", Test2 = "TestCell2", Test3 = "TestCell3" });
        }
    }
```

If you try that code within your application you will see that the selection of a single datarow works correct. The problem in your code is that you assign the same instance of an object over and over again. So in the following line you are creating a new object like this:

```
var data1 = new Test { Test1 = "TestCell1", Test2 = "TestCell2", Test3 = "TestCell3" };
```

The object `data1` gets assigned to your dataGrid1 10 times. When you click on a datarow the gridcontrol checks each row with the `equal` method. You didn't not implement `equals` in your `Test` class which means your objects is equal when their references are equal which is the case because you assigned the same object (and therefore the same reference) 10 times.

Further information from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx):

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.

Implementation of IEquatable:
To check if an object equals another object you can use the IEquatable interface like this:

```
public class Test : IEquatable<Test>
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
    public string Test3 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Test other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Test1.Equals(other.Test1)
            && Test2.Equals(other.Test2)
            && Test3.Equals(other.Test3);
    }
}
```

By overriding the equals method you are overriding the default equalization behaviour which checks by reference if two objects are equal.

Comment: Also UI virtualization takes place when the scrolling involved.

Comment: Thanks. my problem is solved by your answer. But just a question: why are more than one row selected after scrolling, while I've set SelectionMode="Single"?

Comment: Well there are more than one item selected because the objects are in fact equal. SelectionModel "Single" does search the whole list of objects for your object by equalizing the object. If it finds multiple objects which are equal those are selected to. I don't know the internal scrolling behaviour wpf is using maybe the items get reselected after scrolling. I am not sure about that though.